# How do I compile LuaJ?

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I have downloaded LuaJ but it wont compile right. It keeps saying import org.apache.bcel.* is not found during compiling. I setup my workspace by combining core and jse. All the import errors occur in the package org.luaj.vm2.luajc.JavaBuilder
Any help on this compiling issue. I feel like I'm missing a library or something maybe. But I'm not sure

Comment: The fun part about using LuaJ is that it's __already implemented__... :-)

Comment: PS have you tried the [BCEL download page](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/download_bcel.cgi)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Found the library from apache, although all links were dead, I found a copy from somewhere